# is it possible to have a dynamic language statically scoped?

Tags: binding, syntax, scope, programming-languages

I have this question.
If I've a dynamic language divided in unities(subprograms). Is it possible that this language has a static scope?
In case that YES, how it's expressed in the symbols table? this has a field in each row that represent the static chain like the A.R. in Algol style language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most languages have static scope. That includes many dynamic langauges (Python, Ruby, Javascript and even Perl if you use `my` to declare your variables).

> In case that YES, how it's expresed in the symbols table?

The same way it is in any other language. If you encounter a variable declaration (where in some languages "declaration" means "the first time that the variable is assigned to"), the variable is added to the table. Once you reach the end of the scope, it is removed from the table. In some languages the rules may be a bit more complicated (for example in Javascript the variable will be in scope even before its declaration), but that's basically it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The mining of my question is how to search dynamic languages global variables when we have a algol style language the activations registry have a pointer to the their father and with that we can find the global variables. When we have a symbols table, how it's this performed?

Comment: @user2482648 I'm confused by your comment. What you're describing sounds a lot like dynamic scoping (climbing up the stack frame until you find your variable), but ALGOL is lexically scoped, isn't it? Anyway in a lexically scoped language, you find a variable by looking it up in the symbol table. You see a variable and then you do `sym_table[variable.name]` and you get the information of the variable declaration. That's not specific to dynamic languages though.